# how to get screen resolution in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, screen, resolution

I am making an application in BlackBerry. Here i want to find the screen resolution in program. How to find that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code for getting the screen width and height -

```
Display.getWidth();
Display.getHeight();
```

Comment: Be aware that when the virtual keyboard is visible, it will change the value returned by Display.getHeight()

Answer (score 1):

As I remember they are asking to avoid calling `Display.getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods. And asking to use `Screen.getWidth()` and `getHeight()` where it's possible.